# Exposing some Python classes without coupling to file structure

Tags: python, python-2.7

My project consists of several Python classes, split into several files.

```
projname/
    a.py # Has classes A1 and A2
    b.py # Has classes B1 B2 B3
    c.py # Has class C
test/
doc/
bin/
```

I'd like to be able to make some (or all) of those classes public, so that, either from my `bin` dir, or from another Python script, I can do something like:

```
import projname
...
myvar = projname.A1()
```

I can't figure out how to do that. The best I can do so far is:

```
import projname.a
import projname.b
import projname.c

myvar = projname.a.A1()
```

I don't like that for two reasons:

1. I don't want clients of my code to have to know and care what files I used to distribute the classes. I don't want to break clients if I change the files
2. I'd prefer to only expose certain classes to outside the project - not all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `__init__.py` into `projname/` with the following content:

```
from .a import A1, A2
from .b import B1, B2, B3
from .c import C
```

This turns `projname` into a package whose namespace contains whatever `__init__.py` contains, in this case `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2`, `B3` and `C`.

Comment: Super! Thanks.  I'm having trouble understanding all the combinations of import and the subtle differences. Can you recommend a clear documentation or tutorial?